# How to render a component on scroll in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I want to render components below only when the come into view or if they are nearing to come into view.
How do I achieve this in React Native. In React we can use the native JS intersection observer to achieve this but how can we do the same in react native?

Comment: Use flatlist instead of scrollview. FlatList renders items lazily, when they are about to appear, and removes items that scroll way off screen to save memory and processing time. https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#initialnumtorender

Comment: @alvAro365 FlatList only works for similar content. Not for varying components

Answer (score 0):

use a flatlist! flatlist will only render components that are only on the screen, when you scroll down, it will then render the components below. it's a good alternative to scrollView.

Comment: As I mentioned in the above comment. I cannot use Flatlist because I want to render different components not the same component multiple times

Comment: try using a scrollview with onScroll, which when you get close to the bottom, you will render some components (10 components) :

const isCloseToBottom = ({ layoutMeasurement, contentOffset, contentSize }) => {
    const paddingToBottom = 20;
    return layoutMeasurement.height + contentOffset.y >=
      contentSize.height - paddingToBottom;
  };

<ScrollView
onScroll={({ nativeEvent }) => {
          if (isCloseToBottom(nativeEvent)) {
           loadMoreComponents
          }
        }}
        scrollEventThrottle={0}
      >
render something here
</ScrollView>

Answer (score 0):

Use Flatlist as the docs suggest to use flatlist for multiple items render [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist) and for your issue to render different items on the same Flatlist you can add some sort of flag on your data or use the index to decide which component to render like

```
const App = () => {

  const renderItem = ({ item,index }) => (
  <React.Fragment>
    {conditionToRenderOneOfComp ? <ItemA /> : <ItemB/>}
  </React.Fragment>
  );

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```